# Levels of interfaces between the users and the OS

Tags: operating-systems

What are the three levels of interfaces by which users and application programmers interact with the Operating System ?

Comment: Take a Tanenbaum (Modern OS) at local library and discover yourself. ... this question looks much like a homework.

Comment: I am not very good at OS

Comment: hint: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwico-Lru63bAhXiLcAKHQnwCOYQFgg2MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstst.elia.pub.ro%2Fnews%2FSO%2FModern%2520Operating%2520System%2520-%2520Tanenbaum.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2xst9mZQmedrDVgCihMMIh

Comment: If I ask it here it's surely because I could not find a answer on google

Comment: If you found or know one, it will be nice of you to share

Comment: I linked you a 'released' tanenbaum (i saved you walk to library): read at least chapter 1.5 -> 1.7. Aniway: main way OS 'interacts' with software are system-calls a.k.a. API.